# Cocoa switching Keyboard for just current application

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

I can use `TISEnableInputSource` and `TISSelectInputSource` to change the current keyboard.  These calls are documented in [Text Input Source Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Reference/TextInputSourcesReference/Reference/reference.html).  I can not figure out how to do this for just my current application from with the code.  I would like to offer as a convenience to the end users the option of having the keyboard change when the application is in-focus.  I don't want to disturb whatever keyboard they have set for other applications.  This is actually important for this particular application (Foreign Language Dictionary).  Any ideas?

Comment: I received one suggestion:  To reset the keyboard from `NSApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`.  I don't think that this is ideal.  Perhaps someone can tell me for sure, but I don't think that this is called from any type of forced exit, such as kill -9 or kill -15.